# Are $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z[x]$ and $\mathbb Z$ isomorphic in rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The polynomial ring $\mathbb Z_n[x]$ or $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z[x]$, is it isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$?
An assignment question given to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there is an isomorphism $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z[x]$. Then $f(n)=n\cdot f(1)=0$, so that $n=0$, which is impossible.

Comment: But why $f(n)=n$?

Comment: By definition $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$. Thus, inductively, $f(n)=n\cdot f(1)$. However, since $n=0$ in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z[x]$, $n\cdot f(1)$ is just $0$.

Comment: Ook... 0(mod n) right?